# XCode12: Receiving error "Include of non-modular header inside framework module"

Tags: xcode, objective-c++, ios-frameworks, podspec

I am trying to build a private CocoaPods framework 'APod' with other my custom private CocoaPods framework 'BPod'.

I added 'BPod' as a dependency in the podspec file:

```
**APod.podspec**
s.dependency 'BPod'
```

But when trying to run the APod Example project.
I get the error "Include of non-modular header inside framework module" with the following structure:

```
**APod/Classes/WWLocationVC.h**
#import <ComponentKit/ComponentKit.h>   <-- Error happens here
```

I added this code and it still doesn't work:

```
s.user_target_xcconfig= { 'CLANG_ALLOW_NON_MODULAR_INCLUDES_IN_FRAMEWORK_MODULES' => 'YES'}
```

This issue goes away if I import <ComponentKit/ComponentKit.h> in the .m file, but I can't do that.

Does anyone know how to fix it?